# How to delete an employee with his training record in this GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, sql-server-2008-r2

I am a new ASP.NET developer and trying to use a GridView control to show all the employees in the employee table in the database. I am working now in deleting the whole information of any employee in the GridView. I am facing the following probelm and I don't know why:

FYI, I have the following database design:

```
Employee Table: Username, Name, JobTitle, BadgeNo, IsActive, DivisionCode
Divisions Table: SapCode, DivisionShortcut
Groups Table: GroupID, GroupName
Courses Table: CourseID, CourseName, GroupID
Employee_Courses Table: EmployeeID, CourseID
```

***(IsActive is like a flag (bit datatype) to indicate if the employee is in an assignment or not)***

Now, I want the Admin to be able to delete an employee, and to delete of all his training information which is exisited in the Employee_Courses Table. **How to do that?**

My Query for deletion:

```
DELETE employee where dbo.employee.Username = @Username
```

And the code-behind for deleting a record is as following:

```
protected void DeleteRecord(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e) 
    {
        string networkID = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UsersInfoDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
        string deleteCommand = "DELETE employee where dbo.employee.Username = " + networkID;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(deleteCommand, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", networkID);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (SqlException se)
        {
            throw se;
        }
        finally
        {
            cmd.Dispose();
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
        }
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

It works well for the employee who has no training record, but it doesn't work for any employee who has a training record and it gives me the following error:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
>   "FK_employee_courses_employee". The conflict occurred in database
>   "UsersInfoDB", table "dbo.employee_courses", column 'employeeId'. The
>   statement has been terminated.

**So how to solve this issue?**

**UPDATE:**

FYI, Username is the primary key in the Employee Table, and the EmployeeID is a foreign key to that primary key. So how can I delete the employee from the Employee table with all of his information in all other tables.

Comment: You should know that your code is vulnerable to SQL Injections

Comment: You are building your query, and you are passing along a @UserName parameter

Comment: employeeID is the foreignkey of employee table in UserInfoDB ?

Comment: and also see my answer I explain there how to specify a Delete rule. After you specify the Delete RUle the data will be automatically delete from child table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One mistake is in your delete query, you are missing the table name  Employee_Courses 
your query should be this

`DELETE employee from  Employee_Courses  where dbo.employee.Username = @Username`

The error comes because you have a foreign key relation. First delete the data from the child table then delete it from the parent table. The UsersInfoDB has a relationship with the Employee_Courses table, first delete the record from UsersInfoDB, then the SQL SErver will allow you to delete a record from the parent table.

Possible Solution.
Go to your Table design, Right Click on the table, a menu will appear select **Relationships**, a popup window with name **Foreign Key RelationShips** will open, Select your desired key from left pane, Then select **Update and Delete Specification** from the right side and specify the delete rule. For DELETE, you should set it to CASCADE. After setting the Delete rule you don't need to manually remove the record from the child table, Now your code will work, whenever you delete a record from Employee_Courses table it will automatically removed from the child table ( UserInfoDB) as well.

Comment: Just one more question. Is doing this not dangerous for design itself?

Answer (score 0):

First delete the elements in employee_courses_employee where EmployeeID = the employee you want to delete. After removing all the records, you will no longer get the reference constraint.

Execute that first, then Execute the next one(the query you are currently trying to execute I believe it just accessing the employee table)

EDIT: I believe there seems to be no EmployeeID record in your employee table - yet there should be (Is it a Primary Key?). If there is some store of the Employee ID as related to the Username or some other data from your Employee Table, you definitely should first get the Employee's ID, delete all of his records, then delete the employee from the Employee table.

"Reference" constraints refer to things called "foreign keys" which link the data in one table to the data in another. If the "Primary Key" is deleted, the "foriegn Key" wouldnt exist and the connection which links them is garbage, which is why the relationship first must be taken care of before you can delete your data which has the primary key (EmployeeID)

Comment: Yes, Username is the primary key in the Employee Table, and the EmployeeID is a foreign key to that primary key. So how can I delete the employee from the Employee table with all of his information in all other tables.

Answer (score 0):

Make your `DeleteCommand` call a stored procedure. There delete all referencing tables.

If a table has foreign key constraints, you need to delete the entries in the referencing table first. Only then will it let you delete the main record.

In this case, call

```
DELETE employee from Employee_Courses where dbo.employee.Username = @Username
```

before

```
DELETE employee where dbo.employee.Username = @Username
```

Answer (score 0):

First delete data from Employee_Courses table and then

from Employee table. But do you have any EmployeeID/ID column in Employee table?? I mean from

where do you get EmployeeID data for Employee_Courses table.

You have delete data from both table instead of deleting it from one table only.